# Como verificar se vários arquivos estão diferentes do TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, team-foundation-server

Meu cénario é, por uma queda no servidor do TFS, quando o mesmo foi restaurado, toda a minha solução ficou toda "checkada" para o meu usuario, gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de verificar ou listar somente os arquivos checkados para o meu user que tenha alguma diferença do que está na base do TFS.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Nesses casos você pode realizar o check-in pois se o arquivo não foi modificado ele ignora.